# if else structure error

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop, matrix

in this code i have to find our the distance values and i have to save the values which are less than or equal to 425 and greater than zero. i estimated that there are approximately 18000 values in this range and i have to save that all values with there x1, x2, y1, y2 values. but this structure gave me error . var3 (variable_3) gaves correct answer and it gave whole matrix of distances but when we save the values less than 425 then it causes error , kindly help me , Thank you.the var4 matrix gave zero values.

```
    var3 = zeros (258840,1);
    var4 = zeros (18000,5);
    m=1;
    for n = 1: 258840

         x1 = var1 (pairpoints(n,1), 1);          
         x2 = var1 (pairpoints(n,2), 1);
         y1 = var1 (pairpoints(n,1), 2);
         y2 = var1 (pairpoints(n,2), 2);

         % distance formula 
         d1=(((x2-x1)^2)+((y2-y1)^2))^(0.5);

         % save distance values in matrix named var3
         lin = sub2ind(size(var3),n,1);
         var3(lin) = d1;

            if 0<d1<426

              line = sub2ind(size(var4),m,1);
              var4(line) = x1;
              line = sub2ind(size(var4),m,2);
              var4(line) = x2;
              line = sub2ind(size(var4),m,3);
              var4(line) = y1;
              line = sub2ind(size(var4),m,4);
              var4(line) = y2;
              line = sub2ind(size(var4),m,5);
              var4(line) = d1;
              m=m+1;

             end
               end
```

Comment: What is the error message, at what line is the error???

Answer (score 1):

First: It makes it much easier to find the error if the code you provide is runnable; that is you need to provide `var1` and `pairpoints`, or at least explain what they are!

Still I might have found your problem. The problem I can see with your code is the `if`-statement: `if 0<d1<426`. When Matlab sees this it interpret it as `if (0<d1)<426`. Now `0<d1` is a `logical`, that is, it is always either 1 (`true`) or 0 (`false`). There by the if statement is either `if 1<426` or `if 0<426`, so no matter which value you get for `d1`, you will always enter the `if`-branch.

If you want to test if `d1` is less that 426 and greater than 0 you should write something like: `if (0<d1)&&(d1<426)`.

I hope this helps you!